# Any performance concerns with sending a buffer array in express JSON response?

Tags: node.js, json, performance, express, buffer

My nodejs server consumes data from a nodejs JSON API. Some endpoints on the API return image data like so:

```js
let buffer = await getImageBuffer();
res.set('content-type', 'image/png');
res.end(buffer);
```

Which works great. However for a number of complexity reasons, I'd love include a buffer array in a JSON response instead... like so:

```js
let buffer = await getBuffer();
res.json({
  contentType: 'image/png',
  buffer
});
```

**Are there any performance issues w/ including a buffer array in a JSON response like that?** Is there any inherent performance benefit to using `res.end(buffer)` instead? The consuming server is also running nodejs, and will naturally `JSON.parse()` the response from the API.